# background image not scaling with window size

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap

So basically I have a very large image (over 3000 x 2000) and I set it as a background image and want it to scale responsively with window resizing.  However, it still wants to stay at it's original resolution (with the right side clipped off the screen and hidden) even when I set the width to 100% and the container to max-width 100%

html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="image-container">
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  }

#image-container {
  background-image: url(../img/bg.png);
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  }
```

I did edit bootstrap's `.container-fluid` a bit to get rid of its default 15px padding and the fact that it had no width or height.  I'm not exactly sure if bootstrap has some properties that might be causing it, but when I look in the debugger the computed width that's making it so huge is the `width` property in `#image-container` which is just set to 100%.  But it does not have a parent that is set to larger than the viewport that I am aware of. (setting `max-width: 100%;` on the container just makes the image vanish)

Comment: [This](https://jsfiddle.net/3cgr0r3o/2/) seem working to me?

Comment: I don't see why you say it's working.  That fiddle has nothing but blank white space in the result window.

Comment: @Mockingbird - They missed the `html, body { height: 100% }` in the fiddle. [Here is the fixed example](https://jsfiddle.net/x4nd8d75/)

Comment: Actually that shows the problem I have right there, the image's width should fit the width of the window but it extends beyond it, if the height is set to auto then it just gets set to 0 by default unless there is content inside the div.  I want it to keep the image's native ratio inside the div but fill the width of the page completely without having the image getting clipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the percentage property of `border-size` attribute.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  }

#image-container {
  background-image: url(https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8270/8998617248_977cfe9d55_b.jpg);
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  }
```

> http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp